# Different widths being specified on each row of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Anyone know why each `width:xx%` on the table cells are not being used?

Looks like the first row may be set correctly, but the sizes in the second row are being ignored.

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/4fLL8md0/1/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:80%;">A lot of text on 1 line</td>
        <td style="width:20%">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:20%">
            <label>Directory:</label>
        </td>
        <td style="width:80%">
            <input id="directory" readonly="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Short answer: impossibru. This is how tables works, cells in rows are always have equal sizes.

Comment: @antyrat *cells in columns* :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible any simply way. You can achive that only using more than 2 cells in row and group them.

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <col width="20%">
    <col width="60%">
    <col width="20%">

    <tr>    
        <td colspan="2">A lot of text on 1 line</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Directory:</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input id="directory" readonly="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4fLL8md0/2/

As you can see, for this case you need 3 cells with width 20%, 60% and 20%. If you have more rows, more cells or want to divide rows in other percentages, you always need to change the table structure.

Answer (score 1):

Table cells must conform – otherwise it wouldn't be a table! You can use `colspan` to *sorta* overcome this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to achieve the design is totally wrong. There are two ways to do this either use colspan or nested table to achieve this.

You can try the answer given by Panter or try nested table that is the best option as it will be easier to implement and maintain also.